# find all "unknown CSS class" warnings from ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Is it possible to find all instances of these "unknown CSS class" warnings that I am getting from ReSharper?

I have a project with lots of copied code. Ideally, I'd be able to see all these warnings like I see in the Task List, etc.

Also, is it possible to filter for a specific file type like jsx or cshtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the cursor on a code with the warning | hit Alt+Enter | Inspection: "Unknown CSS class" | Find similar issues in file | Find in solution

[image: Find all "unknown CSS class" warnings in a scope]